# How to map the double-qoute (") to something in the vimrc

Tags: vim, neovim

I'd like to map the <kbd>"</kbd> key to something in input mode in Vim and put this into my vimrc.

How do I accomplish that, since this characters introduces a comment?

```
inoremap " ""<ESC>i
```

Would be something I'd like to set, but that doesn't work, `:imap` shows that this mapping isn't set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quote in VimScript only *sometimes* opens a comment. Of course, it could be very confusing for novices, but in this case it just works:

```
inoremap " ""<Left>
```

Comment: Huh, right. Weird, I haven't got it working last time, but it does show it somehow. Anyways, `iunmap`ping it triggers a weird bug in fugitive. Gonna look deeper into it.